# How to install aggdraw with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, aggdraw

I'd like to use aggdraw with Python 2.7. (Is this a dumb idea anyway? I've seen a nice aggdraw example, but I don't want to regress to Python 2.6. Is there an equivalent drawing library working with Python 2.7?) I have Python 2.7.8 64bit installed on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1 64bit.

The installer at http://www.effbot.org/downloads#aggdraw complains about Python 2.6 missing, and `python setup.py install` complains about a missing `vcvarsall.bat`.

So, following all the related posts here, I installed the MS compiler from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266. It's visible in the "Programs and Features" list, and I have a `vcvarsall.bat` in `C:\Users\d031475\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0` now.

Still, `python setup.py install` neither runs in CMD directly, nor in the `MS Visual... Compiler for Python 2.7` command prompt which appeared in my Start menu. It still complains about a missing `vcvarsall.bat`.

EDIT: Even when I append the relevant directory to my path, so that I can run `vcvarsall.bat` from the command line, `python setup.py install` still complains it can't find it. How strange is that?

Comment: Note that the aggdraw module referenced in http://www.effbot.org/downloads#aggdraw is using the outdated agg module version 2.2 . I have ported aggdraw to agg2.4. My version is available at https://github.com/dov/aggdraw and it works fine with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build with "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" you need to use [setuptools >= 6.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) instead of distutils. Try to change the line `from distutils.core import setup, Extension` in `setup.py` to `from setuptools import setup, Extension`.

You'll need to build against the [freetype library](http://www.freetype.org/) to enable text rendering.

The aggdraw project appears to be abandoned. The latest [version 1.2a3](http://svn.effbot.org/public/aggdraw/) is from early 2006 and predates Python 2.7, 64 bit, and Pillow. Expect crashes, especially on 64 bit for Windows.

Unofficial Windows binaries for aggdraw are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#misc.

An alternative to aggdraw is [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) ([Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo)).

Comment: Thanks a lot - I downloaded the 64bit versions for Python 2.7 from your site, and it works now. I have a simple example in aggdraw that seems to exactly fit my problem, but I'll consider pycairo next time!

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to mess around with the Compiler things yourself.

The by far easiest and tested solution is to download the to your environment fitting Windows Binaries for aggdraw from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Once you have it go  in cmd to your download folder and install with pip (use filename of just downloaded whl script.

```
pip install aggdraw-1.2a3-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

DONE!